# caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefRoundError:com/mchange/v2/ser/indirector

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, noclassdeffounderror, c3p0

When I try to use `c3p0` to test a `mysql` database connection, Eclipse shows the following error:

```
caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/mchange/v2/ser/indirector,
```

I googled and was unable to find an answer.

Could anyone help me? I am a java rookie, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what is c3p0. Could you add more details?

Comment: c3p0 - JDBC3 Connection and Statement Pooling,details here http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Comment: Go through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java), you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure that your project is properly loading `mchange-commons-java`, where the stuff you are `com.mchange.v2.ser.*` lives. It is a transitive dependency of c3p0.

Hopefully you are using `c3p0-0.9.5`. Try changing the c3p0 config param [contextClassLoaderSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#contextClassLoaderSource) to `library` to avoid some ClassLoader confusions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are only placing c3p0 jar in tomcat lib. 
If you copy mchange-commons-java jar also than this issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And I am using IntelliJ IDEA. Perhaps you can fix it by follow steps:

- Add c3p0 and mchange-commons-java to your 'libs' folder and add them 
  as 'Library';
- Open 'File->Project Structure->Project
  Settings->Artifacts', then find c3p0-* and mchange-commons-java in
  the 'Available Elements',    and 'Extract Into Output Root'.
- Then
  build artifacts again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing mchange-commons-java-0.2.11 (use your version) jar that contained the com/mchange/v2/ser/indirector class. We need this and c3p0-0.9.5.2 jars to be kept in app/WEB-INF/lib directory.

Just adding that worked!!!